# Azure Chron Webjob Executing Multiple Times per Trigger

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-webjobs

I've got a chron job setup to run every 5 minutes but in the portal logs I seem to always have 10 function invocation logs per run. This is the highest level part of my job:

```
 public class ShipOrderJob
{
    private IShipDateMetBll _shipDateMetBll;
    private Serilog.ILogger _log;
    public ShipOrderJob(Serilog.ILogger log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void ProcessQueueMessage([TimerTrigger("* */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]
    TimerInfo info,
    Serilog.ILogger log)
    {

        using (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(Program.Container))
        {
            _shipDateMetBll = Program.Container.GetInstance<IShipDateMetBll>();
            _shipDateMetBll.ResetLogger(_log);
            _shipDateMetBll.DecorateLogger(log);
            _shipDateMetBll.MoveB2BOrdersIntoProcessingIfShipDateTimeMet();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is how my logs look like: 
[image]

I also know there is an issue because I have serilogger hooked up to slack and today the webjob blew up. Instead of getting one error message I got 6 of the same error messages all thrown within one second of eachother.

**What I've tried:**

I've checked the scale tab to make sure we didn't have 6 instances running. We only have one running. My chron timer seems correct and the function should only run ever 5 minutes. The only scary thing here is I'm using pre-release versions of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`

Comment: Have you tried the following CRON time? `0 */5 * * * *`

Comment: That was it. If you write an answer I can mark it as the correct answer. Although ultimately I don't understand why the first star caused it to run once a second. The first star essentially translates the chron statement to say "run every 5 minutes irregardless what second" and this one says "run every 5 minutes at commencement of the minute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is to do with your current CRON setting.

Basically `*` = *every*

So the expression `* */5 * * * *` means it will run each second every 5 minutes.

Where as the expression `0 */5 * * * *` means it will run every 5 minutes only.